# Soundcloud embed ignores height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, soundcloud

I'm using Featured Video Plus plugin on my Wordpress theme in order to set more types of thumbnails. Youtube and Vimeo works fine but when i try to put a classic Soundcloud embed the height of the widget is ignored.

The plugin says it supports Soundcloud and the height is 166.

Here is how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phet1.png

I don't know what's causing the problem, the plugin, souncloud or my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you.

Comment: I am having the same problem - was this ever resolved?